# ListView стал null

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="ru.unturn.iksa.volountersevent.MainActivity">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview"
            android:layout_width="344dp"
            android:layout_height="495dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Это сам ListView вызываю его через ListView lv = (ListView)findViewByID(R.id.listview);

Но приложение при запуске крашится и выдаёт ошибку: https://pastebin.com/Y2JUmHsT

Если listview существует, как он может быть равен null ?

Comment: А почему "стал"? Он скорее всего и был. Чтобы XML разметка превратилась в UI обьекта, ее надо заинфлейтить. Покажите код, где разметка подключается и где findViewByID вызывается.

Comment: Точно, оставьте как ответ, чтобы я мог отметить его

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML разметка является всего лишь описанием UI. Чтобы на основании этого описания создались UI контролы, разметку нужно "заинфлейтить".

Только после этого можно обращаться к объектам UI, в том числе и с помощью метода `findViewByID()`